# Pytube module not found

Tags: python, pytube

I installed pytube via pip, uninstalled it and reinstalled it couple off times, but always I'm getting an error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytube'".
When I insatlled it via cmd this is what it outputs(warning)

The script pytube.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\vid\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.

trying to fix the problem for like 2 hours now. Help

Comment: Do you have two different versions of python installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Run cmd as -> Right click, Run as Administrator and try again
2. You may have 2 different Python installed, one from anaconda and one independent. Uninstall one and keep the conda one only
3. Reinstall, but run the installer as Administrator
4. Update pip "pip install --upgrade pip"

Answer (score 0):

I repaired that using:
`pip install pytube3`, which adds the newer pytube version which python supports.

Answer (score -2):

I solved this problem by this way:

The warning you're seeing indicates that the script `pytube.exe` is installed in a directory that is not included in your system's `PATH` environment variable. To resolve this issue, you can take the following approach:

### Add the directory to the `PATH`

You can add the directory containing `pytube.exe` to your system's `PATH` environment variable. Here's how you can do it:

1. Open the Start menu, type **Environment Variables** and select **Edit the system environment variables.**
2. In the **System Properties** window, click the **Environment Variables** button.
3. In the **Environment Variables** window, under **System variables** find the **Path** variable and click **Edit**.
4. In the **Edit Environment Variable** window, click **New** and then enter the full path to the directory containing the exe.
5. Click **Ok** to close all the windows.
6. Open a new command prompt or terminal window, and the `pytube` command should now work without the warning.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please be aware that content generated by language models is not allowed on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy